# How can i access nodejs terminal in production to view run time errors

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, terminal, runtime-error

I want to access node app terminal in production if there is a way, as in development we can access terminal to see activities, events and log messages, but in production(cPanel) i did not find such tool which i can use to view runtime error to solve any error in the code.
If you know any solution regard this problem, please answer me, i am looking very seriously at it.Thanks, any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're welcome 
Shared hosts do not have access to the terminal at all
You have to buy the virtual private server (VPS) so you can run your nodejs app and access terminal.

Comment: I appriciate your time and help, Is there any way/trick to know the runtime error?

Comment: @jan how do you run your node app in cpanel? please explain more

Comment: I am hosting my app with namecheap  shared hosting, they provide special build tool for node app https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10047/2182/how-to-work-with-nodejs-app , i had deployed my app successfully and then start with a button.Every thing is good but in production level i am getting an exception at certain point in my app

Answer (score 0):

Use pm2 for production nodejs app.

```
npm i pm2 -g
```

PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i am  new in web dev, i tried pm2 but how can i install it in production globally in cpanel environment